# The value in __init__ doesn't returns correct value?

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-admin

I have a model in django:

```
class Game(models.Model):
gaming = models.BooleanField(default=False)

def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
    super(Game, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
    self.old_gaming = self.gaming
```

Now, when I print the value of `self.old_gaming` it comes out to be `True` instead of `False` while working from an application. Whereas, while I work on django-admin it shows `False`. Why is it showing two different values?

Comment: Can you please share the screenshots of both the admin and the place in the code where you are trying to access this?